# how to run embedded pig program using java in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm new in hadoop. I am using pig 0.14.0 and hadoop 1.2.1. I have successfully run pig from grunt shell and pig batch script in both local and map reduce mode. Now I am trying to run pig from embedded pig in Java.
When I compile my code in eclipse I get following error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory     at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.util.PropertiesUtil.(PropertiesUtil.java:34)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.(PigServer.java:202)  at
>   test.main(test.java:6) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 3 more

```
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE);
            runQuery(pigServer);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void runQuery(PigServer pigServer) {
        try {
            pigServer.registerQuery("input1 = LOAD '/mydata/wct.txt' as (line:chararray);");
            pigServer.registerQuery("words = foreach input1 generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;");
            pigServer.registerQuery("word_groups = group words by word;");
            pigServer.registerQuery("word_count = foreach word_groups generate group, COUNT(words);");
            pigServer.registerQuery("ordered_word_count = order word_count by group desc;");
            pigServer.registerQuery("store ordered_word_count into '/mydata/wct';");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

please add commons dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
```